# How do I get information out of IMMDevice?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, audio, device, wasapi

I'm a complete beginner with regards to IMMDevice, and I need to ask what a good, easy way to get some device out of information out of it is.  In my program, I've already successfully set a pointer to one of those with GetDefaultAudioEndpoint().  Now I just need to be able to get some basic information out of it, like some speaker info or the ID of the speaker or anything like that.  What's a good way to do this that a total beginner would be able to pick up on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devices have various properties attached, and you can read them from a device property store. MSDN gives you a code snippet here:

[Audio Endpoint Devices > Device Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370812%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can also use pre-built utilities to quickly check your devices and see what you can obtain from a `IMMDevice` pointer:

- [How to enumerate audio endpoint (IMMDevice) properties on your system](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2011/06/13/how-to-enumerate-audio-endpoint-immdevice-properties-on-your-system.aspx)
- [Enumerate Audio ‘MMDevice’s](http://alax.info/blog/1279)

The latter presents you the properties like this:

[image]

And you can check source code here http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/EnumerateAudioDevices/MainDialog.h#L72 that it starts from as much as having a `IMMDevice` pointer on hands in line 72.